# How to put a kml into Google maps through my website or send js commands?

Tags: php, javascript, google-maps

I have data on my website about gas stations, with measurement of quality of the gasoline and the gps position of these stations.

My idea is to use Google maps inside my website, just like flightradar24.com with the pins pointing those gas stations addresses. And when clicking on each of these, a balloon shows up with the info on the quality of the gas and diesel.

Other option is when the pin is clicked, goes to another page without the maps, showing more detailed info.

We can do it with kml or javascript commands, but how? Kml is inserted by a php call from my server or is also by js?

How to achieve this?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

There are a couple of ways to do this, assuming you're using the latest version of Google Maps API. You could either
a) build a kml file that contains the points and/or shapes you need and display that on the map
b) iterate through your list of locations (gas stations) and use the marker manager to add individual pins to the map.

Either solution is going to work pretty well and it really just depends on what you prefer to do. I would say that it is probably easier to go with option B and just get a JSON formatted array of locations from the server and use the marker manager to display them on the map. You can then display additional markup or redirect when a marker is clicked.

Your JSON array could be as simple as:

```
[
{title:'Station A', latitude: 38.91912, longitude: 7.123121},
{title:'Station B', latitude: 34.81291, longitude: 30.87173},
{title:'Station C', latitude: 31.00123, longitude: 13.184918}
]
```

Here is a link to the MarkerManager script root (http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/markermanager/). Check out the examples folder for a few quick examples. The docs folder has some details but those pages don't seem to render properly for me at the moment.

To show a KML layer using the maps API you'll need your target KML layer to be accessible by google's server (i.e. hosted on a public server). After that this code should get you in the ballpark:

```
var map; // Reference to your map object you created with 'new google.maps.Map()'  
var url = http://url.to/your.kml;
var kml = new google.maps.KmlLayer(url);
kml.setMap(map);
```

To remove the layer just use this code (assuming kml variable is a reference to the KmlLayer you created above):

```
kml.setMap(null);
```

Here is a link to the KmlLayer class in the Google Maps API documention: https://developers.google.com/maps/documentation/javascript/reference?hl=fr#KmlLayer

Comment: Is this done via JS calls to the Google API js file that I put in my html head as you said?

Comment: Yes, this would all be done in JS. You can get pretty much all the JS code you need by viewing the source of this example: http://google-maps-utility-library-v3.googlecode.com/svn/trunk/markermanager/examples/weather_map.html

Comment: Nice example, but it would be very great if they comment the code so the learning curve would be faster.

Comment: Thank you! Could you give me now an example of putting a kml file into the map via JS? There most be an example like that in the web.

Comment: I've updated my answer with a basic example of adding a kml layer to an existing map object. Remember that your kml file must be accessible by Google's server. It can't just live on your local machine.

Answer (score 1):

Another option that is pretty light on coding is to use Google Fusion Tables.  See [here](http://support.google.com/fusiontables/answer/184641?hl=en&ref_topic=1652595) for the basics.  Essentially you make a Fusion Table (like a spreadsheet) in Google Drive with the Lat/Longs of your gas stations, then send a simple Javascript call to get it and display it on your page.  All the styling of the Infowindows and points can be done without any code on the Fusion Table page.

It would be hard to emulate the flightradar24 website with Fusion Tables, but from your post I don't think you need more than what Fusion Tables can give you.

Comment: veery nice. I learned http://support.google.com/fusiontables/answer/2527132?hl=en&topic=2573107&ctx=topic#custompopup but how to turn this file in my google docs inside of a site that I will create? More: How will my app interact to add more data to this file?

Comment: Adding data from your app can be done via the API - https://developers.google.com/fusiontables/ .  I haven't done it, but I imagine it's going to be harder than simply going to the the Google Fusion Table and adding it from there.  If you want add/edit capability, the accepted answer is probably going to be better.